# Unable to create authentication in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

So I'm getting tired of this, as for some reason this bug seem to have been in existence for so many months, that it must obviously not be bothering a lot of people. Which I fail to see why, as I'm never able to create a basic user authentication system.

The error I get is:

```
@selector={"_id"=>{"$oid"=>BSON::ObjectId('5527d409536962695c000000')}}
Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown operator: $oid
```

this happens as a result of me trying to create a helper method called current_user. Which I do with the following code:

```
private
def current_user
 @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
helper_method :current_user
```

how do I fix this insanely annoying bug?

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the JSON representation of an ObjectId. Here is the solution my team and I have been using.

Add this to concerns/zero_oid_fix.rb

```
module ZeroOidFix
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def serialize_from_session(key, salt)
      record = to_adapter.get((key[0]["$oid"] rescue nil))
      record if record && record.authenticatable_salt == salt
    end
  end
end
```

Then in User.rb add

```
   include ZeroOidFix
```

Make sure that line is below the devise line (if you're using it).